# SQL Server Agent - Semaphore timeout

Tags: sql-server, semaphore

I have a SQL Server Agent Job with one step.  The step executes a stored procedure on the local server, and nothing more.  When the job executes (either manually or scheduled), I receive the following error.  The job fails after about 23 seconds.

> Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A transport-level error has
> occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

However, I have no problem executing the stored procedure manually.  I receive the proper results in less than a second.

The 'semaphore' error tends to be a hardware or network issue.  But since the job is executing on the local server, I am unclear how hardware or network latency could be an issue.

#### UPDATE (things I've tried)

After each of these attempts, I put everything back to its original state.  Each of these attempts has the same results (works when I RDP to the server, fails everywhere else).

- The underlying stored procedure calls out to a linked-server.  I removed these references.
- Assuming the problem is some kind of call out to the AD domain-controller, I used a SQL Login instead of a Windows User.
- I modified the job to run as me (since I can do everything).

Another note:  When executing, the job fails to *start.*  So, it's not even getting to the stored procedure.

Comment: What user do you have the job scheduled to run as?  Sometimes that is a false positive for a user rights issue.

Comment: I've double-checked the user permissions - that's not it.

Comment: In fact, if I RDP into the server, and manually execute the job from there, it works.  The user is a Windows user (not a SQL Login), and we're using AD.

Comment: Can you RDP to the server as that user and execute the job?

Comment: If you haven't seen this already.... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325487

Comment: Thanks for the link; I'm looking into it.  I also added to the original summary.

Comment: However, other jobs work.  These other jobs execute stored procedures and use the same Windows User.

Comment: Oh man, this may fall into the Microsoft abyss of the unexplained.  If you have support with Microsoft, I might suggest having them take a look.  I have seen all kinds of weird stuff that really makes no sense with this issue.

Comment: Side note: if the job is executing on the *local* server, there is no need for Agent to make a *TCP* connection. The connection ought to use shared memory, assuming you haven't disabled that. Double check that there's not still a remote connection hidden somewhere (through a synonym to a remote server, for example).

Comment: A data point for you: the TCP 3 way handshake is limited to 21 seconds. That sounds suspiciously close to your observed 23 second timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem by following below steps...

1.Ensure Query is finetuned
2.Ensure stats and indexes are upto date

Semaphore time outs mostly relate to insufficient memory in the system..So updating stats will help sql server in getting memory estimates right..and this should solve most of timeouts

> But since the job is executing on the local server

I assume you meant ,you are running job in same box as of server..not  remotely..even in this cases ,we faced time outs(general),but we ruled out hardware and network issues through below steps

[TCP Offloading/Chimney & RSS…What is it and should I disable it?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onthewire/2014/01/21/tcp-offloadingchimney-rsswhat-is-it-and-should-i-disable-it/)

changed Remote Login,Remote query time outs(these may not be applicable to your error message)